# Expected ordering of random variables, given pairwise ordering probabilities

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a collection of continuous random variables $V_1, V_2, ... V_n$ and for each $i, j <= n, i \neq j$, $P(V_i > V_j) = k_{i, j}$ is known. Is there an established algorithm for finding an expected order for the random variables? I feel like there's probably some vocabulary associated with this type of problem that I'm missing, preventing me from googling it successfully.

Comment: Yes, something is missing, Jacob.  How is "order" measured such that it may have an expected value?

Comment: Each variable has an (unknown) expected value, the question is if these known probabilities of pairwise orderings is enough to know how the expected values would order them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minor observation for the case $n=3$ (and assuming the probability of any pair of variables being equal is zero, so we ignore cases such as $V_1=V_2$):

By the rule $P[A\cup B] = P[A]+P[B]-P[A\cap B]$ we have by
defining $A= \{V_1<V_2\}$ and $B=\{V_2<V_3\}$: 
\begin{align}
P[V_3<V_2<V_1]&=P[A^c\cap B^c]\\
&= 1-P[A\cup B] \\
&= 1-(P[V_1<V_2]+P[V_2<V_3]-P[V_1<V_2<V_3]) \\
&= 1-k_{21} - k_{32} + P[V_1<V_2<V_3]
\end{align}
So
$$ P[V_3 < V_2 < V_1] - P[V_1 < V_2 <V_3] = 1-k_{21} - k_{32} $$
which means we can determine which is bigger, $P[V_3<V_2<V_1]$ or $P[V_1<V_2<V_3]$, based only on $k_{21}$ and $k_{32}$.